# How to reveal the values used by pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is a pandas DataFrame (holding 100% of strings), exactly like below :

```
    item client type     status                 date
1  item1    bar    O    refused  13/05/2023 15:32:34
0  item1    foo    A  confirmed  01/01/2023 22:32:00
4  item1    foo    A  confirmed  14/05/2023 15:32:34
6  item2    baz    A  confirmed  11/06/2023 09:25:22
7  item2    baz    O  confirmed  15/02/2023 20:20:12
2  item2    qux    O  confirmed  02/04/2023 10:25:33
3  item3    baz    A  confirmed  07/06/2023 00:01:11
8  item3    foo    O  confirmed  18/11/2023 21:50:40
5  item3    qux    O    refused  03/05/2023 12:01:11
```

A pre-sorting is made by me (not sure if it's necessary though):

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["item", "client", "date"])
```

I'm expecting a conditional output based on a boolean value.

If `details=False` :

```
{
    "item1": {"A": 1, "O": 0}    
    "item2": {"A": 0, "O": 2}
    "item3": {"A": 1, "O": 1}
}
```

If `details=True` :

```
{
    "item1": {"A": {"foo": "14/05/2023 15:32:34"}, "O": {}},    
    "item2": {"A": {}, "O": {"baz": "15/02/2023 20:20:12", "qux": "02/04/2023 10:25:33"}},
    "item3": {"A": {"baz": "07/06/2023 00:01:11"}, "O": {"foo": "18/11/2023 21:50:40"}}
}
```

> **THE LOGIC BEHIND** : First, we ignore every refused ordered item.
> Second, if the same `client` orders the same `item` more than once,
> then we valorize the `date` column to take in consideration only the
> last order.

I've managed by miracle to make the first dictionnary using the code below but I unfortunately ignore how to make the second one. SO, any help would be greately appreciated.

```
def agg_items(df, details=False):
    if not details:
        return (
        df.loc[
            (~df[["item", "client"]].duplicated(keep="last"))
            & df["status"].ne("refused")
            ]
            
            .pivot_table(
                index="item", columns="type", values="client",
                aggfunc="count", fill_value=0)
            
            .to_dict("index")
    )

    else:
        # ...
        pass
```

Comment: Why in `item2` the `A` has value `0`?

Comment: Because the client `baz` ordered the `item2` twice, so we keep only the last order for that client/item2 (pair), which is the line with the index 7. The line with index 6 (type A) is therefore dropped. I hope it's a lot clearer now..

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, just pivot on `date`:

```
def summary(df, detailed=True):
    aggfunc = 'count'
    if detailed:
        aggfunc = lambda x: x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).dropna().to_dict()
    return (df.query('status!="refused"')
              .sort_values('date')
              .drop_duplicates(['item','client'], keep='last')
              .pivot_table(index=['item','client'], columns=['type'], values='date', aggfunc='last')
              .reindex(columns=['A','O'])
              .groupby('item')
              .agg({'A':aggfunc, 'O':aggfunc})
              .to_dict('index')
        )

# calls
summary(df)

summary(df, False)
```

Output:

```
# detailed = True
{'item1': {'A': {'foo': '14/05/2023 15:32:34'}, 'O': {}},
 'item2': {'A': {},
  'O': {'baz': '15/02/2023 20:20:12', 'qux': '02/04/2023 10:25:33'}},
 'item3': {'A': {'baz': '07/06/2023 00:01:11'},
  'O': {'foo': '18/11/2023 21:50:40'}}}

# detailed = False
{'item1': {'A': 1, 'O': 0},
 'item2': {'A': 1, 'O': 2},
 'item3': {'A': 1, 'O': 1}}
```